# Hyperledger explorer | start.sh | ssl_transport_security | SSL3_GET_RECORD

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-explorer

I tried to install and run hyperledger explorer using the following URL
[post at medium](https://medium.com/@thanawitsupinnapong/setting-up-hyperledger-explorer-on-fabric-5f1f7cda73b3)
Everything work fine. But finally, I am getting the error

```
************************************************************************************
**************************** Hyperledger Explorer **********************************
************************************************************************************
***** Please check the log [logs/console/console-2019-08-16.log] for any error *****
************************************************************************************

An identity for the admin user: admin already exists in the wallet 

E0816 13:40:17.255321114    4411 ssl_transport_security.cc:1229] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number. 

E0816 13:40:18.256594682    4411 ssl_transport_security.cc:1229] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number. 

E0816 13:40:20.126334198    4411 ssl_transport_security.cc:1229] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number. 2019-08-16T08:10:20.256Z - [31merror[39m: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:7051 2019-08-16T08:10:20.257Z - [31merror[39m: [Channel.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:7051 

E0816 13:40:23.194952082    4411 ssl_transport_security.cc:1229] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number. 2019-08-16T08:10:23.263Z - [31merror[39m: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:7051

FabricConfig, this.config.channels  mychannel
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Explorer Error >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Error :  [ 'Default client peer is down and no channel details available database' ]
Received kill signal, shutting down gracefully
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Closing explorer  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Closed out connections
```

Please give a solution for fixing the issue.

Comment: that blog is an old tutorial and  probably best to source the official docs for latest info: https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer#60-fabric-network-setup----  - at first glance you can check if your container is on the same network `docker network inspect net_byfn  | jq ".[].Containers[].Name" | sort` or whether your explorer container can resolve the byfn nodes eg `docker exec explorer.mynetwork.com ping -c 1 peer0.org1.example.com` etc

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to connect HP Explorer to a HP Fabric network. If you want to disable TLS for Hyperledger Explorer you have to make two changes to the connection-profile. It is usually located at `app/platform/fabric/connection-profile/first-network.json`. The name of the file depends on the network you are using.

You have to set `"tlsEnable": false,` and then change the protocol of the urls of the peers from grpc**s** to grpc e.g. `"url": "grpc://localhost:7051",`

My whole connection-profile looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "first-network",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "client": {
        "tlsEnable": false,
        "adminUser": "admin",
        "adminPassword": "adminpw",
        "enableAuthentication": true,
        "organization": "Org1",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300"
                },
                "orderer": "300"
            }
        }
    },
    "channels": {
        "mychannel": {
            "peers": {
                "peer0.org1.example.com": {}
            },
            "connection": {
                "timeout": {
                    "peer": {
                        "endorser": "6000",
                        "eventHub": "6000",
                        "eventReg": "6000"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Org1": {
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/tmp/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/key.pem"
            },
            "signedCert": {
                "path": "/tmp/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem"
            }
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "/tmp/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
            },
            "url": "grpc://localhost:7051",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TLS is not enabled in your remote site but you are trying to establish TSL connection. I have faced the same error to integrate Client application in my network.

[You can check solution from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58166762/fabric-1-4-handshake-failed-with-fatal-error-ssl-error-ssl-error1408f10bssl/58187128#58187128)