# Fabric 1.4: Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, hyperledger, tls1.2, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I know that this may be duplicate issue. I did not find a valid answer. What can the be wrong here.

I am trying connect to my fabric network using client application. In my current configuration, admin and user enrollment is successful. But whenever I am trying to query in my peer0, it shows this error.

My node verion is 8.9.12 .

```
ccpPath path: /home/hypuser/fabric-samples/servicebook-fabric/connection.json
Wallet path: /home/hypuser/fabric-samples/servicebook-fabric/wallet
E0930 03:49:55.417145688    5824 ssl_transport_security.cc:1238] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number.
E0930 03:49:55.418689495    5824 ssl_transport_security.cc:1238] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number.
E0930 03:49:56.416984736    5824 ssl_transport_security.cc:1238] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number.
E0930 03:49:56.418080418    5824 ssl_transport_security.cc:1238] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number.
E0930 03:49:58.103991314    5824 ssl_transport_security.cc:1238] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number.
E0930 03:49:58.105143769    5824 ssl_transport_security.cc:1238] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number.
2019-09-30T10:49:58.414Z - error: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:7051
2019-09-30T10:49:58.416Z - error: [Channel.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:7051
2019-09-30T10:49:58.416Z - error: [Network]: _initializeInternalChannel: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:7051
Failed to evaluate transaction: Error: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:7051
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLS was not enabled for orderer and peer. I have fixed the problem by enabling **CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED** to **true**

Peer:-

```
# TLS settings
- CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
```

Oderer:-

```
# TLS settings
- ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
```